# loglog plot with matplotlib in pyqt - axes disappear

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to use matplotlib plotting library inside PyQt4 to plot loglog plot. I have added two lines of code in the class:

```
class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """Simple canvas with a sine plot."""
        def compute_initial_figure(self):
            t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
            s = abs((t * 1E+1) * sin(2 * pi * t) + 1E1)

            self.axes.plot(t, s)
            self.axes.set_yscale('log') #added code
            self.axes.set_xscale('log') #added code
```

but then axes disappeared and got an error below. I would like to ask you how can I use matplotlib library inside PyQt4 to plot loglot plot. As seen in the figure below. Python 2.7.5, matplotlib 1.3.0, PyQt 4.10.4

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4.py", line 299, in resizeEvent
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.py", line 148, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1093, in draw
    renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1042, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 754, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 329, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 210, in get_text_width_height_descent
    self.mathtext_parser.parse(s, self.dpi, prop)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 3009, in parse
    self.__class__._parser = Parser()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 2193, in __init__
    - ((lbrace + float_literal + rbrace)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because your x-range includes `0`. True log scales can't reach 0.  If you want to include 0, you'll need to use `'semilog'` instead.

Judging from the error message you're getting, I'd bet you're using a fairly old release of matplotlib? For what it's worth, in newer versions, including `0` will cause the scale to be automatically changed to `semilog` instead of `log`.

Either way, try specifying a semilog scale, and see if that helps.  E.g.

```
self.axes.set(xscale='semilog', yscale='semilog')
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Unfortunately I was upgrading (python, matplotlib) and now I get some new error:

'ImportError: six 1.3 or later is required; you have 1.2.0-mpl'

As soon as I solve this I will reply about your suggestion.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it raises an error:
ValueError: Unknown scale type 'semilog'

I also updated matplotlib (1.3 to 1.4.2) and it works OK with the first code and it also works. I also get the correct result using 'self.axes.lolglog()' but I am having problems displaying grid in loglog plot as 'self.axes.grid(True)' does not work.